# Docker SDK for remote repository

Tags: docker, go

I need to access a private docker registry using the Go SDK. I found "package registry".
I see it has "DefaultSession" object. I can connect to the private registry, but I can't investigate it using the DefaultSession.
Secondly, the registry package contains the Session struct. They wrote it's for the v1 protocol only. Ok, I connect the private repository using the Session:

```
    c := http.Client{}
    indexInfo, err := registry.ParseSearchIndexInfo("repo")
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    endpoint, err := registry.NewV1Endpoint(indexInfo, "", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    session, err := registry.NewSession(&c, &authConfig, endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }

    n, err := reference.ParseNamed("docker.io/repo/image")
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }

    rep, err := session.GetRepositoryData(n)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
```

But GetRepositoryData returns zero images, but they are in the repository. Why?
Is it right way I do access to a remote repository? Is there a v2 SDK for Go?

Comment: can you ouput entire `rep`?

Comment: &{map[] [https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/]}